# ¿Como puedo crear una libreria compartida en Java?

Tags: java

Amigos, como puedo crear un .ear que contenga varios jar para este poder desplegarlo en mi servidor. Quiero crear una libreria compartida para que pueda ser utilizada por otros aplicativos desplegados en ese mismo servidor. Alguien tiene algun ejemplo?

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

¿Pretendes meter varios jars en un ear para que sean accesibles para otras aplicaciones? Esto no funciona así.

Las librerías de una aplicación web están en su directorio WEB-INF/lib y son accesibles solamente para esta aplicación. No importa si empaquetas war o ear.

Si quieres que una librería sea accesible para más de una aplicación debes ponerla en el directorio lib de tu servidor de aplicaciones. Cómo se hace esto y dónde está el directorio lib (o como se llame) de tu servidor depende de tu servidor.

Si pretendes que una funcionalidad se pueda acceder desde varias aplicaciones debes montar un servicio, desplegarlo y que las aplicaciones lo accedan. Pero esto no es "meter jars en ear".

Está claro que esto no responde a tu pregunta "cómo crear librería compartida" y tampoco te puedo dar ejemplos, pero al menos he intentado aclarar cómo puedes hacer lo que pretendes y por qué no puedes hacer lo que te imaginas que se puede hacer.

Saludos.